# Hidden status bar but the cover sheet still intercepts touches

Tags: ios, swift

On iOS 11 with Xcode9 on iPhone 7

I'm having the issue where I can hide the status bar however the notification sheet still intercepts the touch events and doesn't present the user with the normal "tab" on top on the first pull down

Video of what I am talking about

https://youtu.be/OApYsxIksFI

View controller used in the video. It's just a single page app.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }


}
```

Comment: I think, he is setting his status bar to lightcontent. Something like this in viewDidLoad method or viewWillAppear method: `UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent, animated: true)`

Comment: No the status bar is actually gone proved with `view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue`

Comment: Do you think I should update the youtube video to show that? The point was its the blank app Xcode gives you for single page apps just adding prefersStatusBarHidden and this has the same effect in all of my apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior was changed with iOS 11. All apps, even those that hide the status bar, will have edge gestures that launch notification center and control center by default. If would like the previous behavior, you can override the `preferredScreenEdgesForDeferring` of the view controller for which you want the older behavior.

For more information about these changes checkout the [What's New in Cocoa Touch](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/201/) WWDC 2017 session.